# Problem with binomial series: $ \big( 1+ \frac{a^2}{x^2} \big)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $

Tags: binomial-theorem

I'm trying to solve a exercise from a physics book. In that situation $x \gg a$ and $x > 0$.

I weren't able to solve, so I saw the solution:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}=\frac{1}{|x| \sqrt{1 + \frac{a^2}{x^2}}}=\frac{1}{x} \left( 1+ \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} 
$$
Hence:
$$
\frac{1}{x} \left( 1+ \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{x} \overbrace{ \left( 1 -\frac{a^2}{2x^2} \right)}  = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{a^2}{2x^3}
$$

I couldn't understand what had happened to $ \left( 1+ \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

So, in the generalized binomial theorem, we have

$$(1-x)^{-s} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{s+k-1}{k} x^k$$

Here, it seems $s=1/2$ and $x \mapsto -a^2/x^2$ giving

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k-1/2}{k} (-1)^k \frac{a^{2k}}{x^{2k}}$$

Note that since $x \gg a$, the relatively high-order terms have negligible contribution. While I wouldn't say strict equality applies, we would reasonably have, just by using the $k=0,1$ terms,

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-1/2} \approx \binom{-1/2}{0} - \binom{1/2}{1} \frac{a^2}{x^2}$$

Note that, for these binomial coefficients, we define

$$\binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1)(\alpha - 2) \cdots (\alpha - (k-1))}{k!}$$

where it equals $1$ for $k=0$.

Therefore

$$\binom{-1/2}{0} = 1 \qquad \binom{1/2}{1} = \frac 1 2$$

and

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-1/2} \approx 1 - \frac 1 2 \frac{a^2}{x^2}$$